# SQLite bitwise query returning unexpected results

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-core, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

Here's my query (EF Core 7 and resulting raw SQL):

```
Me.Context.Patients.Where(Function(Patient) Patient.BloodType.ReceivesFrom.HasFlag(BloodType))
```

```
SELECT "p"."Id", "p"."BloodTypeId", "p"."CityId", "p"."Code", "p"."Email", "p"."FirstName", "p"."LastName", "p"."ZipCodeId", "b"."Type"
      FROM "Patients" AS "p"
      INNER JOIN "BloodTypes" AS "b" ON "p"."BloodTypeId" = "b"."Id"
      WHERE ("b"."ReceivesFrom" & 4) = 4
```

...and here's the result:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id | BloodTypeId | CityId |  Code | Email                    | FirstName  | LastName   | ZipCodeId | Type |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |           4 |     46 | U6UJI | oliver.runte@gmail.com   | Abbigail   | Cremin     |        12 |    4 |
|  2 |           5 |     88 | LV892 | eunice81@gmail.com       | Donnell    | McKenzie   |        94 |    8 |
|  5 |           8 |     44 | 5F6TN | susie.schaefer@gmail.com | Nedra      | Stokes     |        66 |   64 |
|  7 |           5 |     16 | 6LQ61 | eileen76@gmail.com       | Jairo      | Jakubowski |        69 |    8 |
| 10 |           5 |      8 | BI56C | kristopher46@yahoo.com   | Modesto    | Reichert   |        33 |    8 |
| 11 |           5 |     94 | R8LP2 | connie_king@gmail.com    | Raphaelle  | Murphy     |        47 |    8 |
| 16 |           5 |     66 | 8TC6V | amber62@hotmail.com      | Daphney    | Bechtelar  |        94 |    8 |
| 17 |           4 |     45 | DM52B | lucas_mraz@yahoo.com     | Durward    | Larson     |        67 |    4 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The problem is that the query results are very inaccurate.

Here's the `BloodTypes` data:

```
----------------------------------------
| Id | ReceivesFrom | DonatesTo | Type |
----------------------------------------
|  1 |            0 |         0 |    0 |
|  2 |            3 |       255 |    1 |
|  3 |            3 |       255 |    2 |
|  4 |           15 |       204 |    4 |
|  5 |           15 |       204 |    8 |
|  6 |           51 |       240 |   16 |
|  7 |           51 |       240 |   32 |
|  8 |          255 |       192 |   64 |
|  9 |          255 |       192 |  128 |
----------------------------------------
```

The supporting enum:

```
<Flags>
Public Enum BloodTypes As Byte
  <Description("?")> Unknown = 0
  <Description("O+")> OPositive = 1
  <Description("O-")> ONegative = 2
  <Description("A+")> APositive = 4
  <Description("A-")> ANegative = 8
  <Description("B+")> BPositive = 16
  <Description("B-")> BNegative = 32
  <Description("AB+")> ABPositive = 64
  <Description("AB-")> ABNegative = 128
End Enum
```

...and the `Patients` data (fake, created with [Bogus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bogus)):

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id | BloodTypeId| CityId | Code  | Email                           | FirstName | LastName   | ZipCodeId |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |          4 |     46 | U6UJI | oliver.runte@gmail.com          | Abbigail  | Cremin     |        12 |
|  2 |          5 |     88 | LV892 | eunice81@gmail.com              | Donnell   | McKenzie   |        94 |
|  3 |          6 |     85 | SNTB4 | kristi_bergnaum26@gmail.com     | Paige     | Watsica    |         4 |
|  4 |          2 |     24 | 4XMHO | claire97@gmail.com              | Gregg     | Wilkinson  |        26 |
|  5 |          8 |     44 | 5F6TN | susie.schaefer@gmail.com        | Nedra     | Stokes     |        66 |
|  6 |          2 |     88 | 6C1LG | bridget88@yahoo.com             | Brice     | Runolfsson |        55 |
|  7 |          5 |     16 | 6LQ61 | eileen76@gmail.com              | Jairo     | Jakubowski |        69 |
|  8 |          6 |     12 | 50U3K | angelina62@yahoo.com            | Fredy     | Heathcote  |        54 |
|  9 |          7 |      2 | DD4YB | teri41@yahoo.com                | Dorothea  | Littel     |        20 |
| 10 |          5 |      8 | BI56C | kristopher46@yahoo.com          | Modesto   | Reichert   |        33 |
| 11 |          5 |     94 | R8LP2 | connie_king@gmail.com           | Raphaelle | Murphy     |        47 |
| 12 |          7 |     92 | AALG8 | janice67@gmail.com              | Willy     | Pouros     |        28 |
| 13 |          7 |     82 | LCH1T | dwayne_legros@yahoo.com         | Everardo  | Lang       |         6 |
| 14 |          6 |      8 | 8HNN2 | patrick_gleichner78@hotmail.com | Koby      | Purdy      |        53 |
| 15 |          3 |     24 | FWG31 | irene.prosacco@hotmail.com      | Gardner   | Mueller    |        27 |
| 16 |          5 |     66 | 8TC6V | amber62@hotmail.com             | Daphney   | Bechtelar  |        94 |
| 17 |          4 |     45 | DM52B | lucas_mraz@yahoo.com            | Durward   | Larson     |        67 |
| 18 |          7 |     57 | 4750K | levi_lang64@yahoo.com           | Joelle    | Bashirian  |        58 |
| 19 |          2 |     18 | O8Z0Q | marguerite4@yahoo.com           | Loy       | Ratke      |        98 |
| 20 |          1 |      6 | 8UKAB | paulette.moore8@hotmail.com     | Christa   | Gibson     |        48 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

See the problem?

`A+` blood (flag `4` in the `BloodTypes` enum) can receive from types `A+/-` and `O+/-` (source: [Red Cross](https://www.redcrossblood.org/donate-blood/blood-types.html)), so the query should be returning exactly 11 rows whose `BloodTypeId` is either `2`, `3`, `4` or `5`. (I've ensured that 11 random rows satisfying this requirement exist in my `Patients` test data.)

Flag `4` (`A+`) has a `ReceivesFrom` value of 15, which is the sum of types `1`, `2`, `4` and `8` (`O+`, `O-`, `A+` and `A-`).

Here's my `BloodTypes` table definition (no indexes, but I doubt that matters):

```
CREATE TABLE "BloodTypes" (
    "Id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "ReceivesFrom"  INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "DonatesTo" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "Type"  INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_BloodTypes" PRIMARY KEY("Id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

The frustrating part is that the query results include invalid rows and omit valid rows. For example, check `ID#5` in the results: there's no way that `64` (`AB+`) fits into `15`. That's a mathematical impossibility.

And where are `PatientId`s `4`, `6`, `15` and `19`? Why were they omitted? They're within the scope of acceptable blood types for `A+`.

What's going on here? Why is SQLite producing such wildly inaccurate results?

Comment: I don't see why that query should return O entries. 1 and 2 bitwise anded with 4 are always going to be 0...

Comment: I'm not *exactly* sure I follow you there, but we're bitwise anding 4 with 1, 2, 4 and 8 in this case, not just 1 and 2. Did I misunderstand you?

Comment: `("b"."ReceivesFrom" & 4) = 4` Only 4 rows in the BloodTypes table match that condition; only rows joined with one of those 4 will be returned. Ones with ids 4, 5, 8 and 9.

Comment: Same, I think your expectation/understanding of the bitwise operation may be incorrect. 3 & 4 = 0.   15 & 4 = 4. Bitwise Anding is asking "is this bit position a '1' in this value. " If you want values where the 4 bit is 0, you want "= 0" not "= 4". Your query asks for matches where Receives From Includes A+ and it appears that is what the query gave you.

Comment: @StevePy: But the query also gave me AB+, which is 64. That falls outside of the range of acceptable values of 1, 2, 4 and 8. And it failed to include the valid values of 1, 1, 2 and 1 (Patient IDs 4, 6, 15 and 19).

Comment: @Shawn: The SQL statement is a translation by EF Core. Run this code in a LinqPad VB Program really quick, based on that enum: `Dim eBloodType As BloodTypes` `eBloodType = BloodTypes.OPositive Or BloodTypes.ONegative Or BloodTypes.APositive Or BloodTypes.ANegative` `eBloodType.HasFlag(BloodTypes.ABPositive).Dump`. You'll get `False`, as you should. But this SQLite query is returning `True` for that comparison. THAT'S the big mystery.

Comment: I'm just looking at the "raw query" and sample data. Sounds like you're wanting the linq expression to calculate something else other that what it is. Can't help there; I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: @Shawn: `"Only 4 rows in the BloodTypes table"` But we're not querying the BloodTypes table. We're querying the Patients table, to find rows whose BloodType.ReceivesFrom value contains the specified flag (A+).

Comment: The query is doing a join on the two tables.

Comment: @Shawn: Yes, of course. I simplified my description for brevity. But the concept is the same. We want all `Patient`s whose `BloodType.ReceivesFrom` value contains the specified flag. The ORd value of 15 most definitely does not contain 64 (AB+), so it should not be included in the query results. But it is, thus the problem.

Comment: @Shawn: OK, got it. I've been looking at it backward. Blood type `AB+` (64) has a `ReceivesFrom` value of 255, which means it's able to receive from `A+` (4), and is why it's being returned in the query results. I was thinking (incorrectly, I see now) that the resulting type had to be included in the query filter type's `ReceivesFrom`. It's the other way 'round. So your earlier statement, `ids 4, 5, 8 and 9`, is spot on correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the query is behaving correctly. It's my expectations that were incorrect. I was looking at the problem 180° backward.

Instead of trying to shoehorn `AB+` (64) into the `A+.ReceivesFrom` aggregate (15)—which obviously doesn't work—we must go the other way and fit `A+` (4) into the `AB+.ReceivesFrom` aggregate (255). That works.

Which makes perfect sense when we break it down.

The rule: We want all patients who can receive from `A+`. Simple.

That's `A` and `AB`, according to the [chart](https://www.redcrossblood.org/donate-blood/blood-types.html). Those two have `ReceivesFrom` aggregates of 15 and 255, respectively. `A+` (4) fits into both of those, thus the query returns all `A/AB` blood types.

Problem solved. In fact, it never even was a problem.